# Invalid UTF-8 detected in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, utf-8, quoted-printable

I'm having an issue while encoding an email body using `utf8` and `quoted-printable`

```
bodyHtml = utf8.decode(quotedPrintable.decode(resData['body-html']));
```

In heroku logs, it says

```
2017-05-04T05:49:54.312348+00:00 app[consumerWorker.1]: 
/app/node_modules/utf8/utf8.js:194
2017-05-04T05:49:54.312360+00:00 app[consumerWorker.1]:         throw 
Error('Invalid UTF-8 detected');
2017-05-04T05:49:54.312362+00:00 app[consumerWorker.1]:         ^
2017-05-04T05:49:54.312362+00:00 app[consumerWorker.1]: 
2017-05-04T05:49:54.312363+00:00 app[consumerWorker.1]: Error: Invalid 
UTF-8 detected
```

I have created a runkit, https://runkit.com/kiranlm/590abc3746b5b70012ffd7f8

Answer (score 0):

Try this if your using english utf-8:
from a terminal run

```
heroku config:add LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

if you want to check this:

```
    $ heroku run bash
Running bash attached to terminal... up, run.2
u20415@022e95bf-3ab6-4291-97b1-741f95e7fbda:/app$ irb
irb(main):001:0> "a".encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

Comment: Thanks @damian-lattenero, I tried this, now the encoding is utf8 in heroku, but the error still there,